# Add class when element is created

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a class to be added whenever div element is created.

```
var divElement = document.createElement('div')
```

should return

```
<div class="foo"></div>
```

**EDIT:**

I do not want to repeatedly add Class whenever I create another `document.createElement('div')` using className or setAttribute. I should just write `document.createElement('div')` and it should add class in future.

Can we change at document.createElement and do it?

Comment: Sorry mate, did not quite understand the update to the question. You can just add the `className` wherever required.

Comment: @Harry Can default class be added just by document.createElement('div')

Comment: None that I am aware of mate. You can probably use a function and call it wherever needed?

Comment: did you try to make a function which create a div with class name you want. like this: function createDiv(clsName){var div =document.createElement('div');div.className = clsName;return div;}

Comment: @WillWang Yes, that works. But, I am looking for different solution. Can we change at document.createElement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to override the behavior of `document.createElement` -- really, really want to -- then:

```
document.createElement = (function() {
    var original_createElement = document.createElement.bind(document);
    return function(tagName, cls) {
        var elt = original_createElement(tagName);
        elt.className = cls;
        return elt;
    };
}());
```

A couple of notes about this:

1. We use a IIFE in order to isolate `original_createElement` inside the closure.
2. We need to do the `bind` on `document.createElement` because that function requires the `document` context.
3. This function is designed to be used as in `document.createElement('div', 'foo')`. If you really, really want `foo` to be added to every single element you ever create in the future, then remove the `cls` argument and do `elt.className = 'foo';` instead.

But in any case I don't recommend doing this at all.

Instead, as described in the comments and other answers, define your own functionn:

```
function createElementWithClassFoo() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('foo');
    return div;
}
```

Or generalize it to any class:

```
function createElementWithClass(cls) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add(cls);
    return div;
}
```

Then call

```
var divElement = createElementWithClassFoo();
var divElement = createElementWithClass('foo');
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add the following line to the code before appending the child. This would add the class to the element that was just created.

```
divElement.className = 'foo';
```

like given below:

```
var divElement = document.createElement('div') ;

divElement.className = 'foo';

document.body.appendChild(divElement);
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/919Lft9e/)

**Using a pre-defined function to reduce repetition:**

```
function appendDefaultDiv(){
    var divElement = document.createElement('div') ;

    divElement.className = 'foo';
    divElement.innerHTML = "Some Text";

    return divElement;
}


document.body.appendChild(appendDefaultDiv());
```

[**Fiddle Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/919Lft9e/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className)

```
var divElement = document.createElement('div');
divElement.className = 'foo';
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9jzudxfj/1/)

Answer (score 1):

use `.className`:

```
var divElement = document.createElement('div');
    divElement.className = 'foo';
```

**Reference**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className

Answer (score 1):

You can use function to avoid repetition.

```js
var createDiv = function() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'what-ever-class';
  return div;
};

console.log(createDiv());
console.log(createDiv());
```

```html
Open console ....
```

Answer (score 0):

u can add property like this divElement.className = 'foo';

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = "100px";
div.style.height = "100px";
div.style.background = "red";
div.style.color = "white";
div.innerHTML = "Hello";
div.id="vik";
div.setAttribute('id', 'myid');
div.setAttribute('class', 'myclass');

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var $div = $("<div>", {class: "foo"});
$("body").append($div);
```